# Potential bug with placement of newsletters link on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, design

It's plausible that it was intentional, but given how it looks I suspect that it wasn't - in Safari 5.1 (7534.48.3) on Lion the "newsletters" link at the top of stackexchange.com is not in line with the rest of the links, but on its own line underneath:

[image]

There's ample space next to "top users" where it would look a lot better

Comment: can't repro on Safari/Win

Comment: I can reproduce on OS X Lion in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox. [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QN0q2.png)

Answer (score 1):

The `margin-right` on `ul.navMain li` has been reduced by 1px, so this should be fixed now.

(I was able to reproduce it in Safari on Snow Leopard.)